# Github Repos are not showing the Languages statistics

Tags: github, statistics

I have the followings Githubs repos which are not showing the Languages used for the projects. I mean that the following bar that represent the percentage of different languages is not showing on these repos:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgaLN.png)

https://github.com/nferrari3444/ExpenseManager/tree/master
https://github.com/nferrari3444/DeLasAnimas/tree/master

Thanks in advance for the support.
Regards
Nicolás

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that was a matter about the branch. In order to see the Languages statistics of the project, the project should be in the main branch. Now both projects has their content in the main branch and therefore is possible to observe the Languages.